# Choosing players for command execution

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm making a Minecraft map, and it's a team PVP. I want to testfor the player who has press a button to choose a kit, and give **that** player the kit he chose. I don't want to use `@p` as the kit may be given to the wrong player.

Comment: Thank you Skylinerw for editing my question and pointing out my mistakes almost immediately! Next time, I'll pay more attention to grammar and spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to determine which player clicked the button because that information is neither transferred through redstone nor does a scoreboard objective exist to auto-increment for activating a button. `@p` with the origin set to the button's coordinates would be the most accurate if relying on a button.

```
/give @p[x=0,y=5,z=0] minecraft:stone
```

---

What you could use instead of a button is a sign, which has text component and clickEvent support. For example, the following creates a sign that, when right-clicked by a player, will add a "clicked" label to the player.

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:wall_sign 0 replace {Text1:"{\"text\":\"Click\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"scoreboard players tag @a[c=1] add clicked\"}}",Text2:"[\"\"]",Text3:"[\"\"]",Text4:"[\"\"]"}
```

You'd then use your external mechanism to target players with that tag, followed by removing that tag.

```
/give @a[tag=clicked] minecraft:stone
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=clicked] remove clicked
```